# Can some one help me with working code for Restassured post request with Authorization Header

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, rest-assured

I'm new to Restassured Webservice automation. 
I'm able to get OAuth2 token and save it to a string. But when I pass this string in Authorization header, I'm getting 403 error.

Working code to store token in a string:

```
    `String response = given()
            .params("grant_type", "XXX", "scope", "XXX")
            .auth()
            .preemptive()
            .basic("XXX","XXX")
            .when()
            .post("api/path")
            .asString();

    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(response);
    accessToken = jsonPath.getString("access_token");
    String pswd = "Bearer " + accessToken; `
```

Code not working is below:

```
    `given().header("Authorization", pswd)
    .body(content).with().contentType("application/json")
    .when()
    .post("/api/path")
    .then().statusCode(200);`
```

I'm getting 403 error.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following

```
`given().auth().oauth2(accessToken).
    .body(content).with().contentType("application/json")
    .when()
    .post("/api/path")
    .then().statusCode(200)`
```